# Queue trigger for blob processing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As per [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#incsharp), we can create a queue trigger instead of blob trigger to avoid [drawbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-plan-works) of blob trigger. 
I have a few questions around this which these docs don't answer:

My question is should I send explicit queue message with blob name on the queue hub to trigger the function and process the blob ? Or can I somehow automate this so that the storage account/container can send a queue message once a blob is uploaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it yourself, i.e. send a queue item with blob name in it every time you save a new blob to the storage.